# why local variable gets empty on timer_click event?

Tags: c#, timer, webforms

when I call Timer1_Tick(null, null)  event programmatically message gets empty?
how can I solve this problem OnMessageReceieve called when a event has fired.

```
string message = string.Empty;
public void OnMessageReceieve(string message)
{
   //  I have a message in message variable
   txtMessage.Text += message;
   Timer1.Enabled = true;
   Timer1_Tick(null, null);
   // UpdatePanel1.Update();                  
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //message variable gets empty here?
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
   {
      txtMessage.Text += message;
   }                
}
```

Comment: Have you using AutoPostBack="true" for timer, if it false try to set true

Answer (score 8):

You are confusing the **member** `message` you declard here:

```
string message = string.Empty;
```

with the **parameter** you (accidently?) named the same `message`.

Inside your `OnMessageReceive` method you don't set the *member* value, but inside your `Timer1_Tick` you access that member.

Immediate solution would be to set the member in `OnMessageReceive`:

```
public void OnMessageReceieve(string message)
{
     txtMessage.Text += message;

     // set member!!
     this.message = message;

     Timer1.Enabled = true;
     Timer1_Tick(null, null);
     // UpdatePanel1.Update();          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string message = string.Empty; //Never change.

public void OnMessageReceieve(string message)
{
   //  I have a message in message variable (this is a parameter, not a field class)
   txtMessage.Text += message;
   Timer1.Enabled = true;
   Timer1_Tick(null, null);
   // UpdatePanel1.Update();                  
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //message variable gets empty here?
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message)) //<-- this.message
   {
      txtMessage.Text += message;
   }                
}
```

> solution:

```
string message = string.Empty;
public void OnMessageReceieve(string message)
{
   //  I have a message in message variable
   this.message = message; //<-- Add this line.
   txtMessage.Text += message;
   Timer1.Enabled = true;
   Timer1_Tick(null, null);
   // UpdatePanel1.Update();                  
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //message variable gets empty here?
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
   {
      txtMessage.Text += message;
   }                
}
```